# Activator.CreateInstance(type, args) replaces null with default value for non-nullable constructor parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0, coreclr

Why does this code compile and run when `param2` is non-nullable? I can't find anything in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-6.0#system-activator-createinstance(system-type-system-object())) saying that a default value is used when `null` is passed to a non-nullable constructor parameter via `Activator.CreateInstance(...)`?

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        Class @class = (Class)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Class), "param1value", null);
        //@class.Param1 = "param1value"
        //@class.Param2 = 0
    }

    public class Class
    {
        public Class(string param1, int param2)
        {
            Param1 = param1;
            Param2 = param2;
        }
        public string Param1 { get; }
        public int Param2 { get; }
    }
```

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance doesn't have the normal checks that the compiler would perform if you just called the constructor directly.

Comment: Worth noting that [it works this way in .NET 4.7.2 too](https://dotnetfiddle.net/40iP4e), so this is not something introduced by Core. This is likely behavior that's been there for a long time. Even better, if you declare overloaded constructors with (e.g.) one taking an `int` and another taking a `short`, passing `null` will not even get you an ambiguous match exception -- it will pick the `short` constructor, seeing that as "better" (narrower, most likely). Between `int` and `float`, `int` wins. ...this (along with performance) is why sane people eschew this form of `CreateInstance`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert are you questioning my sanity :-D Seriously though, that's some good information to know, thank you, can I ask where you got that from? I did see something ages ago about possibly updating the new() constraint to allow parameter types to be specified but I haven't picked up on any updates ... dunno if you know if that's been/will be implemented?

Comment: I got it 40 minutes ago by playing around with dotnetfiddle, no insider info there. I do have personal experience with `Activator.CreateInstance` being ridonkulously slow when called in a tight loop, although I know they've reduced the costs with newer versions (but boxing is still notable). The `new` constraint is implemented through [`Activator.CreateInstance<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance#system-activator-createinstance-1), which *is* fast as the JIT can optimize it as an intrinsic (but, obviously, you can't pass parameters with that).

Comment: For every other dynamic creation scenario, most things beat `Activator.CreateInstance` in terms of predictable semantics and speed -- a `Func<...,MyType>` delegate, expression trees, cached `ConstructorInfo` -- just the ability to avoid the cost of boxing value types alone and/or matching the correct constructor tends to be worth it. Obviously, for a one-off creation of an instance it doesn't really matter.

Comment: The "`new` with parameters" feature is a very old idea, but it's never left the development stage, and it seems unlikely now that it will be implemented, given how it keeps getting tangled up with other, more general proposals (most notably [shapes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/164)). [This](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/769) is the issue covering it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks again for the info, ended up questioning my own sanity and changed my approach so I now use `new()` and then call a initialiser method rather than relying on a constructor. The `new()` approach also ended up making some other things a lot simpler too which was a bonus :0)

Comment: @JeroenMostert dunno if you want to bang your first comment into an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: No, a decent answer would includes some background on why `Activator.CreateInstance` behaves this way, and how it disambiguates between constructors, things which no doubt have a fascinating background but that I'm not willing to spend time on at this moment.